Use arabic numerals for amsthm section numbering when sections are numbered with roman numerals
For reasons of internal consistency, I have labeled the sections in my document using lowercase roman numerals followed by a dot, using the following command in the preamble:
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\roman{section}.}
However, I also want my theorems to be numbered as section.theorem. This can be achieved using the amsthm package and putting the following command in the preamble:
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
However, amsthm now uses the roman numerals for section numbers, which renders as
This is obviously not desirable. How do I tell amsthm to use arabic numerals instead? Simply replacing the section in the above command with \arabic{section} does not work.

Welcome! What document class are you using? Can you please add a minimal example of code to play with? By the way, do you want that \ref{<label to a section>} prints the (roman) number followed by a period?

In general it is not a good idea to have that trailing dot in the various \the... commands as other commands makes the assumption that it does not end with a dot.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I would like to suggest that you employ the secdot package to affix trailing dots to the "numbers" in section-level, subsection-level, etc headers. And, to use arabic numerals for theorem environments, be sure to issue the instruction
\renewcommand\thetheorem{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem}}

after defining the theorem environment in the preamble.

Note the absence of trailing dots in the cross-references to section-level and subsection-level headers.
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{secdot}
\sectiondot{subsection} % apply to subsection-level headers as well
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\alph{subsection}} % just for this example

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand\thetheorem{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3} % just for this example

\section{Hello world} 
\label{sec:hello}

\subsection{Once upon a time}
\label{sec:once}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:bla} 
bla bla bla 
\end{theorem}

\bigskip\noindent
Cross-references to section \ref{sec:hello}, subsection \ref{sec:once}, and theorem \ref{thm:bla}.

\end{document}

